# I need help sorting out an if statement in a simplexml statement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Some basic background ...

I have a form that enters data to an xml file and another page that displays the data from teh xml depending that it meets the requirements . All of this I have managed to get done and thanks to a member on here I got it to show only the data as long as it has todays date and status is out . But I am left with the problem of trying to sort an if statement which needs to show data if it has it or show another div if not .

My Code ...

```
$lib  = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml");
$today = date("m/d/y");
$query = $lib->xpath("//entry[.//date[contains(., '$today')]] |    //entry[.//status[contains(., 'out')]]");


foreach($query as $node){

echo "<div id='one'>$node->name</div>
<div id='two'>$node->notes</div> 
<div id='three'><div class='front'>$node->comments</div></div>";
 }
```

So to reiterate if query returns matched data do the foreach else show another div

I only wish to know the right code for the if else statement if soneone could help with this  I would be very grateful and will up vote any answer as soon as I have the reputation in place . I also apologise in advance if the question has been asked before or if it is too vague thanks again .

Comment: Can you expand on what you require to check with the if?

Comment: if $query function returns true then echo them if not use an else hope this helps thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If xpath fails to resolve the path, it will return `false` [(see here)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php#59873). Wrap the foreach loop in a simple check:

```
if( $query ) {
    foreach($query as $node){
        ...
    }
}
else {
    // Echo the special div.
}
```

Since PHP is loose typed, if xpath happens to return an empty array, this check will also handle that case. Be aware that if the `xpath` call does return `false`, there may be a separate error at play that may require additional or alternative handling.

Comment: Probably is the correct answer and will accept it as teh answer when the other part of my code has been corrected as my query is returning results wether either of the answers match and I need it to match both thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you so very much for your if statement now that the rest of the code is working correctly I can now see that it was exactly what was required for the job as soon as I have the required reputation for giving an up vote I shall be back to do so thank you for your quick and ultimately correct response thank you once again